# Is it necessary for the Exchange Data Collector Sets to be running at all times?

Tags: performance, exchange-2013

I have an Exchange 2013 server, this data collecting is running at all times with non-negligible i/o load on the disks. How is the data collected used by Exchange ? Is it possible (or recommended) to just stop the collecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are used by Exchange's built-in [health monitoring (Managed Availability)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482056(v=exchg.160).aspx).  They do use resources and take up disk space, and it's possible to stop them (apparently you have to do it in task scheduler or it comes back), or even to turn off health monitoring altogether.

Whether it's recommended to turn off health monitoring, well.  No, not really.  Not unless it's causing an actual problem.  Only you can say for certain whether the increased I/O qualifies as a problem serious enough to reduce health monitoring, but I'd be inclined to err on the side of leaving it on.  I'd actually be inclined to err on the side of throwing more resources at the box, if possible.